# SMTP email with javax.mail config issues

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I can send emails from a linux server by typing the following on the console, without any issues:

> mail -s "Test Subject" testemail@gmail.com < /dev/null

I try to send it via a Java app, using javax.mail via:

```
public void sendMail() throws MessagingException
{
    final Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
    final Message msg = new MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(p));
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    msg.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    msg.setSubject("Test");
    msg.setText(body);
    Transport.send(msg);
}
```

but I get a

> Causing: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1

error, is this due cause I need to replace

> p.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");

with my server's address? if yes, where can I find what I should put there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a mail server running on your local machine?

Have you configured sendmail to route messages to your mail server?

If you run "mail -v ..." it should tell you what the mail command is doing to send your message.

But yes, most likely, you want to configure JavaMail to connect directly to your mail server, which is probably not running on your local machine.  You'll find more help in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).

Comment: I am doing this in a box I am sshing into.
"mail -s "Test Subject" testemail@gmail.com < /dev/null" 
command works

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions.  Did you try running "mail -v ..."?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I wasn't clear.  I meant to add the "-v" option to all the other options and arguments you were specifying, i.e.,  "mail -v -s "Test Subject" testemail@gmail.com < /dev/null".  That's what the "..." meant in my message.

Comment: thanks for you message, I get 
null message body; hope that's ok
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <username>.

Is this normal?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're actually **receiving** these test messages in your mailbox, right?  Normally I would expect to see the SMTP protocol exchange but if you're not getting it then I don't know exactly how your mail system is configured.  The point of this testing was to determine how the "mail" command is getting messages to Gmail.  Since we aren't getting that information, you might as well just go back and [change your Java program to talk to Gmail directly](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).